# combine two dictionaries into one, with elements from dict2 taking precedence

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
  # Combine both dictionaries into one, with each key listed 
  # only once, and the value from guests1 taking precedence

Rorys_guests = { "Adam":2, "Brenda":3, "David":1, "Jose":3, "Charlotte":2, "Terry":1, "Robert":4}
Taylors_guests = { "David":4, "Nancy":1, "Robert":2, "Adam":1, "Samantha":3, "Chris":5}

print(combine_guests(Rorys_guests, Taylors_guests))
```

Want this output

```
{"Adam": [2, 1], "Branda": 3, "David": [1, 4] ...}
```

with value from guests1 i.e.Rorys_guests dict will take precedence first .i.e for Adam key value is [2,1]

Comment: `dict1.update(dict2)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression first answer works for your problem, I tried it.

Comment: if `dict` have the same key then from which dictionary you want to get value @nishikant

Comment: {"Adam":[2,1],"Branda":3,"David:[1,4].....} want this output with value from guests1 i.e.Rorys_guests dict will take precedence first .i.e for Adam key value is [2,1]

Comment: I added the desired output from the comment to the question. It looks like no one has given the correct answer by the current moment because the desired output was unclear.

Answer (score 2):

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
    #Update function will add new values and update existing values in the dictionary
    guests2.update(guests1)
    return guests2

Rorys_guests = { "Adam":2, "Brenda":3, "David":1, "Jose":3, "Charlotte":2, 
"Terry":1, "Robert":4}
Taylors_guests = { "David":4, "Nancy":1, "Robert":2, "Adam":1, "Samantha":3, 
"Chris":5}

print(combine_guests(Rorys_guests, Taylors_guests))
```

Answer (score 2):

**output**: `{'Adam': [2, 1], 'Brenda': 3, 'David': [1, 4], 'Jose': 3, 'Charlotte': 2, 'Terry': 1, 'Robert': [4, 2], 'Nancy': 1, 'Samantha': 3, 'Chris': 5}`

---

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
  # Combine both dictionaries into one, with each key listed 
  # only once, and the value from guests1 taking precedence
  g=guests1
  
  for key,value in guests2.items():
    if key in g:
      g[key]=[g[key],value]
    else:
      g[key]=value
      
  return g
Rorys_guests = { "Adam":2, "Brenda":3, "David":1, "Jose":3, "Charlotte":2, "Terry":1, "Robert":4}
Taylors_guests = { "David":4, "Nancy":1, "Robert":2, "Adam":1, "Samantha":3, "Chris":5}

print(combine_guests(Rorys_guests, Taylors_guests))

output: {'Adam': [2, 1], 'Brenda': 3, 'David': [1, 4], 'Jose': 3, 'Charlotte': 2, 'Terry': 1, 'Robert': [4, 2], 'Nancy': 1, 'Samantha': 3, 'Chris': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.5 or above

```
z = {**Rorys_guests , **Taylors_guests }
```

Comment: Correct answer. Just to be clear with the given example combined_guests = {**Rorys_guests, **Taylors_guests}

Comment: i done that but issue is combine both dictionaries into one, with each friend listed only once, and the number of guests from Rory's dictionary taking precedence, if a name is included in both dictionaries. Then print the resulting dict

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
    out = guests1.copy()
    for key, val in guests2.items():
        out[key] = val
    return out
```

EDIT: copied guests2 instead of guests1

Comment: this prints only taylors_guests dict but we want to combine both in one with value from dict2 taking presedence...e.g{"Adam":[2,1],"Branda":3,"David:[1,4]....}

Answer (score 0):

This might help. This will give precedence to `Rorys_guests` and will not include those from `Taylors_guests` if both have the value.

```py
Taylors_guests.update(Rorys_guests)
return Rorys_guests
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
    lst ={}
  # Combine both dictionaries into one, with each key listed
  # only once, and the value from guests1 taking precedence
    lst =guests1
    for name,friend in guests2.items():
        if name in lst:
             pass
        else:
            lst[name] =friend
    return lst
Rorys_guests = { "Adam":2, "Brenda":3, "David":1, "Jose":3, "Charlotte":2, "Terry":1, "Robert":4}
Taylors_guests = { "David":4, "Nancy":1, "Robert":2, "Adam":1, "Samantha":3, "Chris":5}

print(combine_guests(Rorys_guests, Taylors_guests))
```

Open for any kind of suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
  # Combine both dictionaries into one, with each key listed 
  # only once, and the value from guests1 taking precedence
    combine = guests1
    for guest, friend in guests2.items():
      if guest not in combine:
        combine[guest] = friend
    return combine

Rorys_guests = { "Adam":2, "Brenda":3, "David":1, "Jose":3, "Charlotte":2, "Terry":1, "Robert":4}
Taylors_guests = { "David":4, "Nancy":1, "Robert":2, "Adam":1, "Samantha":3, "Chris":5}

print(combine_guests(Rorys_guests, Taylors_guests))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here: def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
                     empty={}
                     empty.update(guests1)
                     empty.update(guests2)
                     for key,val in guests1.items():
                         empty[key]=val
                     return(empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
  precedence=''

  guests2.update(guests1)

  for key,value in guests2.items():

    if key in guests1:
      precedence=value+1
      guests2[key]=precedence
  return guests2
```

output:

```
{'David': 2, 'Nancy': 1, 'Robert': 5, 'Adam': 3, 'Samantha': 3, 'Chris': 5, 'Brenda': 4, 'Jose': 4, 'Charlotte': 3, 'Terry': 2}
```

Comment: check indentations. Its currently incorrect and also add context to prevent down-voting and to make your answer quality enough to compete with the other seven answers. EoR. Welcome and enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
  # Combine both dictionaries into one, with each key listed 
  # only once, and the value from guests1 taking precedence
  guests1.update(guests2)
  return guests1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
    # Combine both dictionaries into one, with each key listed
    # only once, and the value from guests1 taking precedence
    for key,value in guests2.items():
        if key in guests1:
            if guests1[key] < guests2[key]:
                guests1[key] = value
        else:
            guests1[key] = value
    return guests1

Rorys_guests = { "Adam":2, "Brenda":3, "David":1, "Jose":3, "Charlotte":2, "Terry":1, "Robert":4}
Taylors_guests = { "David":4, "Nancy":1, "Robert":2, "Adam":1, "Samantha":3, "Chris":5}

print(combine_guests(Rorys_guests, Taylors_guests))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a correct answer as the question was unclear about the desired output. Fixed the question — the desired output was in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, as the OP submitted their question some time ago, but I guess I will submit my answer:

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
   # Combine both dictionaries into one, with each key listed 
   # only once, and the value from guests1 taking precedence
   guests2.update(guests1)
   return guests2
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note the `update()` method i.e `dict1.update(dict2)` will not work here as it will defeat the purpose of the output desired by replacing the contents.

Solution:

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
  # Combine both dictionaries into one, with each key listed 
  # only once, and the value from guests1 taking precedence
  for guest,friend in guests2.items():
    if guest in guests1:
      guests1[guest] = [guests1[guest], friend]
    else:
      guests1[guest] = friend
  return guests1
  

Rorys_guests = { "Adam":2, "Brenda":3, "David":1, "Jose":3, "Charlotte":2, "Terry":1, "Robert":4}
Taylors_guests = { "David":4, "Nancy":1, "Robert":2, "Adam":1, "Samantha":3, "Chris":5}

print(combine_guests(Rorys_guests, Taylors_guests))
```

Output:

```
{'Adam': [2, 1], 'Brenda': 3, 'David': [1, 4], 'Jose': 3, 'Charlotte': 2, 'Terry': 1, 'Robert': [4, 2], 'Nancy': 1, 'Samantha': 3, 'Chris': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):

for key in guests2.keys():

```
if key in guests1:
    del guests2[key]
guests1.update(guests2)
return(guests1)
```

Rorys_guests = { "Adam":2, "Brenda":3, "David":1, "Jose":3, "Charlotte":2, "Terry":1, "Robert":4}
Taylors_guests = { "David":4, "Nancy":1, "Robert":2, "Adam":1, "Samantha":3, "Chris":5}

print(combine_guests(Rorys_guests, Taylors_guests))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).